# WordPress shortcode function for Flickr Collections returns 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to reuse [this jQuery code](http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/qpVdU/6/) for a WordPress shortcode but I can't get it to work. I checked for escaping issues which seem to be OK but run out of ideas what else could be wrong...

Here's the code inside `functions.php` file in WordPress:

```
function flickr_collections($atts, $content=null) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(  
        'user_id' => 'USER-ID',
        'collection' => 'COLLECTION-ID',
        'num' => '12',  
        'sort' => 'random',  
        'size' => 's',
        'api_key' => 'API-KEY'
    ), $atts));

    return ' 
<style type="text/css"> 
</style>
<div id="flickr-photos"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.collections.getTree&collection_id=' . $collection . '&api_key=' . $api_key . '&user_id=' . $user_id . '&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data.collections.collection, function (cid, set) {

            var collectionTitle = set.title;

            $("#flickr-photos").append(\'<ul class="photoset"></ul>\');

            $.each(this.set, function () {

                var photosetId = this.id;
                var photosetTitle = this.title;
                var photosetDesc = this.description;
                var photosUrl = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=' . $api_key . '&photoset_id=\' + photosetId + \'&media=photos&format=json&jsoncallback=?&per_page=6";

                $.getJSON(photosUrl, function (data) {
                    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (pid, photo) {
                        var photoId = photo.id;
                        var photoTitle = photo.title;
                        var photoSecret = photo.secret;
                        var server = photo.server;
                        var farm = photo.farm;
                        var photo_url = "http://farm" + farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + server + "/" + photoId + "_" + photoSecret + "_q.jpg";
                        var photo_urlm = "http://farm" + farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + server + "/" + photoId + "_" + photoSecret + "_m.jpg";
                        $(".photoset").append(\'<li><a href="\' + photo_urlm + \'" title="\' + photoTitle + \'"><img src="\' + photo_url + \'" /></a></li>\');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
';  
}  
add_shortcode('flickr', 'flickr_collections');
```

The short code is then called with `[flickr]` or `[flickr collection="COLLECTION-ID"]`.

**EDIT:**

I've tried another approach where the jQuery script is enqueued externally and the parameters are [passed](http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/) onto it with `wp_localize_script` function. But it still doesn't work...

**functions.php**

```
function flickr_shortcode($atts, $content=null) {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'flickr-shortcode', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flickr-shortcode.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20131105' );

    extract(shortcode_atts( array(  
        'user_id' => 'USER_ID',
        'api_key' => 'API_KEY',
        'collection' => 'COLLECTION_ID',  
        'thumb_size' => 'q',
        'pic_size' => 'm',
        'num' => '12',  
        'sort' => 'random'
    ), $atts));

    return '<div id="flickr-gallery"></div>';
    wp_localize_script( 'flickr-shortcode', 'flickrParams', $atts );
}  
add_shortcode('flickr', 'flickr_shortcode');
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var userId = flickrParams.user_id;
    var apiKey = flickrParams.api_key;
    var collectionId = flickrParams.collection;

    var url = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.collections.getTree&collection_id=' + collectionId + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?';

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data.collections.collection, function (cid, set) {

            var collectionTitle = set.title;

            $('#flickr-gallery').append('<ul id="flickr-collection"></ul>');

            $.each(this.set, function () {

                var photosetId = this.id;
                var photosetTitle = this.title;
                var photosetDesc = this.description;

                var photosUrl = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=' + apiKey + '&photoset_id=' + photosetId + '&media=photos&format=json&jsoncallback=?&per_page=6';

                $.getJSON(photosUrl, function (data) {
                    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (pid, photo) {
                        var photoId = photo.id;
                        var photoTitle = photo.title;
                        var photoSecret = photo.secret;
                        var server = photo.server;
                        var farm = photo.farm;
                        var thumbUrl = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoId + '_' + photoSecret + '_q.jpg';
                        var photoUrl = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoId + '_' + photoSecret + '_b.jpg';
                        $('#flickr-collection').append('<li><a href="' + photoUrl + '" rel="shadowbox" title="' + photoTitle + '"><img src="' + thumbUrl + '" /></a></li>');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Yes, it says "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')". Thanks.

Comment: are you including the Jquery library on the page?

Comment: jQuery is included in WordPress by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! The `shortcode_atts()` / `extract()` functions were incorrectly used resulting in parameters not being passed onto jQuery script properly. Also `return` was moved down a bit. The correct code:

**functions.php**:

```
function flickr_shortcode( $atts, $content=null ) {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'flickr-shortcode', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flickr-shortcode.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20131105', true );

    $params = shortcode_atts( array(
        'user_id' => 'USER_ID',
        'api_key' => 'API_KEY',
        'collection_id' => '', /* REQUIRED! */
        'thumb_size' => 'q',
        'pic_size' => 'b',
        'num' => '3'
    ), $atts );
    extract( $params );
    wp_localize_script( 'flickr-shortcode', 'flickrParams', $params );

    return '<div id="flickr-gallery"></div>';
}  
add_shortcode( 'flickr', 'flickr_shortcode' );
```

**flickr-shortcode.js**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var userId = flickrParams.user_id;
    var apiKey = flickrParams.api_key;
    var collectionId = flickrParams.collection_id;
    var thumbSize = flickrParams.thumb_size;
    var picSize = flickrParams.pic_size;
    var numPerPhotoset = flickrParams.num;

    var url = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.collections.getTree&collection_id=' + collectionId + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?';

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data.collections.collection, function (cid, set) {

            var collectionTitle = set.title;

            $('#flickr-gallery').append('<h2><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/' + userId + '/collections/' + collectionId + '/" title="Go to Flickr Gallery Page" target="_blank">' + collectionTitle + ' Gallery</a></h2><ul></ul>');

            $.each(this.set, function () {

                var photosetId = this.id;
                var photosetTitle = this.title;
                var photosetDesc = this.description;

                var photosUrl = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=' + apiKey + '&photoset_id=' + photosetId + '&media=photos&format=json&jsoncallback=?&per_page=' + numPerPhotoset;

                $.getJSON(photosUrl, function (data) {
                    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (pid, photo) {

                        var photoId = photo.id;
                        var photoTitle = photo.title;
                        var photoSecret = photo.secret;
                        var server = photo.server;
                        var farm = photo.farm;

                        var thumbUrl = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoId + '_' + photoSecret + '_' + thumbSize + '.jpg';
                        var photoUrl = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoId + '_' + photoSecret + '_' + picSize + '.jpg';

                        $('#flickr-gallery ul').append('<li><a href="' + photoUrl + '" title="' + photoTitle + '"><img src="' + thumbUrl + '" /></a></li>');

                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

and **style.css**:

```
#flickr-gallery {
    margin: 20px 0;
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#flickr-gallery ul {
    margin: -3px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    clear: both;
}

#flickr-gallery ul li {
    float: left;
    max-width: 31%;
    max-width: -webkit-calc(33.333% - 6px);
    max-width:         calc(33.333% - 6px);
    margin: 3px;
}

#flickr-gallery ul li a {
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid white;
}

#flickr-gallery ul li a:hover {
    border-color: #993c0b;
}
```

Amend the above to suit your needs.

Usage in WordPress:

```
[flickr collection_id="XXX"]
[flickr collection_id="XXX" num="1"]
[flickr collection_id="XXX" thumb_size="m" num="4"]
```

etc.